# Отправка httpdelete запроса на сервер

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, xmlhttprequest, javascript-events

Проект asp net core.
Есть APIController обрабатывающий удаление пользователя:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class APIFriendsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly Db_usersContext _context;

        public APIFriendsController(Db_usersContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // DELETE: api/APIFriends/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Friend>> DeleteFriend(long id)
        {
            var friend = await _context.Friend.FindAsync(id);
            if (friend == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Friend.Remove(friend);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return friend;
        }       
    }
```

На странице написал JS функцию, которая перебирает все строки body table, выбирает помеченные на удаление, и отправляет запрос на сервер для удаления выбранных записей:

```
 function deleteSelected(idObject) {

        var table = document.getElementById(idObject);
        var rows = table.rows;
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 1, iLen = rows.length - 1; i < iLen; i++) {
            var checked_ = table.rows[i].cells[21].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked;
            if (checked_ == true) {

                var idFriend = table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
                var url = "http://localhost:48329/api/APIFriends/DeleteFriend/" + idFriend;

                fetch(url, {
                    method: 'DELETE',
                //    body: JSON.stringify(data)
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Функция JS падает на

```
fetch(url, {
                    method: 'DELETE',
                //    body: JSON.stringify(data)
                });
```

с ошибкой:

> DELETE http://localhost:48329/api/APIFriends/DeleteFriend/%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%206 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Почему-то вместо корректного найденного id объекта при отправки получается такая вот абракадабра

> %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%206

Но причина наверное не только в этом.

Проблему со строкой запроса удалось решить удалив лишние пробелы. Новый вариант JS-функции:

```
function deleteSelected(idObject) {

    var table = document.getElementById(idObject);
    var rows = table.rows;
    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 1, iLen = rows.length - 1; i < iLen; i++) {
        var checked_ = table.rows[i].cells[21].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked;
        if (checked_ == true) {

            var idFriend = table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
            idFriend = idFriend.trim();
            var url = "http://localhost:48329/api/APIFriends/DeleteFriend/" + idFriend;

            fetch(url, {
                method: 'DELETE',
            //    body: JSON.stringify(data) 
 "Content-Type" header
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка осталась:

> DELETE http://localhost:48329/api/APIFriends/DeleteFriend/6
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) deleteSelected @ Friends:741 onclick
> @ Friends:84

Попробовал использовать вместо функции fetch() ajax() - ошибка осталась прежней:

```
       $.ajax({
                url: url_,
                type: 'DELETE',
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('Пользователи удалены');
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function (result, status, er) {
                    alert("error: " + result + " status: " + status + " er:" + er);
                }
            });
```

Ошибка:

> DELETE http://localhost:48329/api/APIFriends/DeleteFriend/6 404 (Not
> Found) send @ jquery.min.js:2 ajax @ jquery.min.js:2 deleteSelected @
> Friends:745 onclick @ Friends:84

В чем причина? Как можно исправить?

Comment: Потому что вы взяли из ячейки таблицы всё включая пробелы. Вообще идея брать id и html «попахивает»

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а как правильней будет?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, проблему со строкой запроса удалось решить удалив лишние пробелы. Обновил код в вопросе. Ошибка осталась

Comment: У вас в комментарии написано ` // DELETE: api/APIFriends/5`, а вызываете `http://localhost:48329/api/APIFriends/DeleteFriend/"`. Откуда и зачем взяли `DeleteFriend`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, туплю, думал нужно прописывать - Контроллер->Метод. Комментарий то не я писал )

Comment: Этот код делает множество запросов, удаляя по одному объекту. Правильнее было бы сделать метод, который принимает список объектов (айдишников) и удаляет сразу их все. Тогда это делалось бы всего одним запросом.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, для этого нужно использовать POST запрос? А со странице как передать всё кучей?

Comment: Или post, или как и сейчас - delete. Передавать, например, список id в виде json. PS: я сперва написал, что можно и get, но это я был неправ: в соответствии с REST, get-запрос не должен менять состояние.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, можете дать ссылку на какой-нибудь пример реализации подобного способа

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, сделал как посоветовали, но у меня выдает 400-ю ошибку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1272365/post-запрос-с-json-массивом-на-сервер-падает-с-ошибкой-400-bad-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы задаете неверный url. Сделайте так:

```
var url = "http://localhost:48329/api/APIFriends/" + idFriend;
```

Связано это с вашей же настройкой маршрутизации:

```
// DELETE: api/APIFriends/5
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Friend>> DeleteFriend(long id)
```

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо!