# POST-запрос с json массивом на сервер падает с ошибкой "400 (Bad Request)"

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, javascript-events

Проект asp net core. Есть APIController обрабатывающий удаление пользователей:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class APIFriendsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly Db_usersContext _context;

        public APIFriendsController(Db_usersContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }        
        // DELETE:
        [HttpPost("DeleteFriends")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<Friend>>> DeleteFriends([ModelBinder] long [] idFriends)
        {
            List<Friend> friends = new List<Friend>();
            friends = await Task.Run(()=>SearchFriends(idFriends));

            await Task.Run(() => RemoveFriends(friends));

            return friends;
        }

        private List<Friend> SearchFriends(long[] idFriends)
        {
            List<Friend> friends = new List<Friend>();
            foreach (long id in idFriends)
            {
                Friend friend = _context.Friend.Find(id);

                if (friend != null)
                {
                    friends.Add(friend);
                }
                else { friends.Add(null);}
            }
            return friends;
        }

        private void RemoveFriends(List<Friend> friends)
        {
            foreach(Friend friend in friends)
            {
                if (friend != null)
                {
                    _context.Friend.Remove(friend);
                    _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

На странице написал JS функцию, которая перебирает все строки body table, выбирает помеченные на удаление и добавляет их в json-массив, после чего отправляет этот json-массив в POST запросе на сервер для удаления:

```
function deleteSelected(idObject) {

        var table = document.getElementById(idObject);
        var rows = table.rows;
        var jsonMasId = [];

        for (let i = 1, iLen = rows.length - 1; i <= iLen; i++) {
            var checked_ = table.rows[i].cells[21].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked;
            if (checked_ == true) {

                var idFriend = table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
                idFriend = idFriend.trim(); //Удаляем пробелы в начале и в конце                  
                jsonMasId.push(idFriend);
            }
        }

        if (idFriend.length>0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:48329/api/APIFriends/DeleteFriends/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(jsonMasId),
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('Пользователи удалены');
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function (result, status, er) {
                    alert("error: " + result + " status: " + status + " er:" + er);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Когда создается/отправляется ajax-запрос возникает ошибка:

> POST http://localhost:48329/api/APIFriends/DeleteFriends/ 400 (Bad
> Request)
> send  @   jquery.min.js:2
> ajax  @   jquery.min.js:2
> deleteSelected    @   Admin:551
> onclick   @   Admin:79

В чем причина? Как можно исправить?

Comment: а вы уверены, что `jsonMasId` имеет правильный контент, т.е. список id, которые содержит только числа и никаких других символов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на следующий нюанс:

```js
var arr = [];
arr.push('123');
arr.push('345');
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
arr = [];
arr.push(123);
arr.push(345);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

```
["123","345"]
[123,345]
```

То есть вы передаете в контроллер `string[]`, а не `long[]`.

Это можно исправить двумя способами:

1. Записывать в массив сразу числа, а не строки

```js
jsonMasId.push(Number.parseInt(idFriend));
```

2. Принимать в контроллере как массив строк, а не чисел

```cs
[HttpPost("DeleteFriends")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Friend>>> DeleteFriends([ModelBinder] string[] idFriends)
{
    long[] data = idFriends.Select(long.Parse).ToArray();
    // ...
}
```

Я склоняюсь к первому варианту, потому что ту работу, которую можно делать на фронте, лучше делать на фронте.

Еще обратите внимание на то что вы стартуете зачем-то 2 разных потока для выполнения операции, которые выполняются последовательно, можно упростить.

```cs
[HttpPost("DeleteFriends")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Friend>>> DeleteFriends([ModelBinder] long[] idFriends)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => RemoveFriends(SearchFriends(idFriends)));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вы правы. Отдельная благодарность за совет по коду контроллера

Comment: А можете ещё подсказать, как сделать, чтобы после удаления страница у пользователя обновилась?

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir `success: function (response)` внутри хоть обновляйте страницу, хоть что угодно делайте.

Comment: покажите, как внутри неё отправить запрос на обновление? Я в js плохо шарю, если честно

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir перезапишите значения HTML нод с использованием новых данных. Немного программирования на JS, не обязательно обновлять страницу, можно изменить текущую.

Comment: Вот опять не понял о чем вы ) Можете ссылку кинуть на какой-нибудь пример или материал на эту тему?

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir https://javascript.info/modifying-document

Comment: Это получается мне нужно будет заново нарисовать таблицу, потом определить, какие у меня строки остались и перезаполнить эту таблицу значениями оставшихся строк?

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir Вы можете нарисовать ее даже сервером и отдавать в ответе от контроллера вместо json. Простор для творчества огромный. Но обновлять страницу после AJAX запроса - бессмыслица. Если вам нужно обновление страницы, тогда не AJAX надо делать, а обычный запрос, который вернет вам обновленную страницу в сборе, но вы же зачем-то AJAX начали использовать, а это обычно делают, чтобы страницу не обновлять, и динамически изменять.

Comment: да на самом деле я об этом не задумывался, просто посмотрел примеры в интернете и решил сделать по аналогии. Пока плохо представляю и как таблицу js-ом рисовать и как вернуть обновленную страницу в сборе из API, потому что сейчас у меня страница формируется mvc контроллером - он просто возвращает представление

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir изучайте вопрос, здесь парой комментариев не отделаться.